# Um componente em cima do outro

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou com probleminha que não acho como resolver, eu tenho um activity como na foto abaixo, o problema é, que quando eu emulo o aplicativo, o Button e o textView vão para baixo dos dois LinearLayouts coloridos(azul e verde).

[image: PrintScreen do que está acontecendo]

Gostaria de saber como atribuir uma propriedade para o Button e para o textView, para que eles fiquem por cima dos Layouts

Obs: não queria colocar o Button e o textView dentro dos Layouts coloridos.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.uriel.aaa.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00008B"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#008B45"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="aaa"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Testar"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonStart"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Pode compartilhar o XML de layout?

Comment: Fala Uriel, tenta colocar os buttons depois dos layouts no XML, mas como o professor Mateus disse, é melhor que você mande o XML, Abraços.

Comment: opa, botei ali, tinha esquecido, desculpe

Comment: o layout principal da activity é Framelayout?

Comment: Você colocou todo o xml do layout na pergunta? Não há um GroupView que seja "root" ou "pai de todos" como um RelativeLayout, LinearLayout ou FrameLayout?

Comment: Isso ta dentro de um relativeLayout, mas quando eu copiei e colei não apareceu desculpe, no print da pra ver ali na arvore

Comment: Poderia postar o código Java da Activity referente a este layout?

Comment: @UrielKindermann, executei aqui e apareceu normalmente o TextView e o Button por cima dos layout. Teria como você colocar o código da activity para que possamos tentar descobrir o que está acontecendo?

Answer (score 3):

O android já tem um layout que faz o seus filhos de sobreporem, é o `FrameLayout`, substitua o `RelativeLayout` por ele assim:

```
<FrameLayout
   ... // width, height e tudo do RelativeLayout aqui>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00008B"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#008B45"/>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:text="CHAPÉU SELETOR"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/textView"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Testar"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonStart"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Com esse `Layout` os elementos já vão ficar sobrepostos.
Qualquer dúvida é só comentar.

Comment: Creio que no caso dele o problema pode estar relacionado com o código da activity, pois efetuei os testes com o layout dele e funcionou

Comment: Também realizei teste com exatamente o layout dele e funcionou. Não acredito que o problema seja no xml como o @VitorHenrique. Vamos esperar pelo código da Activity.

Comment: É verdade tambem esqueço que as vezes o problema nem sempre é aonde a gente pensa kkk. Mas como só foi mostrado um lado do problema só consegui fazer isso

Answer (score 1):

Experimenta por assim, pode ser que funcione!!

Caso nao funcina diz para eu tentar de outra maneira

```
<FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="CHAPÉU SELETOR"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/textView"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Testar"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonStart"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Você não explicou o que fez, apenas colocou um código que nem diferença para o código da pergunta parece ter. Explique o que fez, por favor...

Comment: esquecime de iniciar o <FrameLayout
Vou editar a minha resposta

Comment: esquecime de uma coisa e é logo down votes :)

acho que para a proxima basta pesquisres um pouco,porque ja foi respondida a esta pergunta:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29740456/overlay-floating-button-in-linear-layout

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072946/how-do-i-create-overlay-button-in-my-android-layout

Nao custa nada fazer umas pesquisas :D

Comment: Francisco, não acredito que tenham negativado você por causa de um erro no seu código, porque isso alguém editaria por você inclusive. Isso só ocorreu porque você não explicou o que fez e porquê fez. Você apenas colou o código como resposta, é necessário gerar entendimento com sua resposta...

Comment: Sim tens razao,para a proximo explico melhor,

Ja deixei 2 links para ver toda a informacao possivel sobre o assunto e de facil entendimento!!

Answer (score 0):

me desculpem, eu solucionei o caso trocando a ordem, botando o textView e o Button no final do RelativeLayout, eu tinha postado o codigo deste jeito, mas no meu projeto não sei o porque eu tinha desfeito isso colocado o textView e o Button no inicio do codigo. Agora deu tudo certo, agradeço a todos pelas respostas, muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Inverta a ordem do código.

No Android a ordem dos fatores altera o produto :)
Se não for isso, troquei o emulador e verifique se funciona.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.uriel.aaa.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:elevation="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="aaa"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="Testar"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00008B"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#008B45"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá. O contraintLayout é o que mais utilizo, e lá, a ordem dos fatores pode sobrepor sim.

```
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/fbutton_color_clouds"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="Bloco 40 cm"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textColor="@color/fbutton_color_wet_asphalt"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="152dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="484dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/fbutton_color_clouds"
            android:checked="false"
            android:duplicateParentState="false"
            android:text="Bloco 33 cm"
            android:textColor="@color/fbutton_color_wet_asphalt"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="27dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="484dp" />

    </RadioGroup>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="185dp"
        android:layout_height="103dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Os blocos de EPS podem ter  40cm ou 33cm de largura. Escolha o que irá ser utilizado"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/radioGroup2"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="149dp" />
```